# How switching between Open JDK and JDK on Windows 10?

Tags: java

I am working on some projects that use different JDKs. For this reason, I need to frequently change the JDK version, between OpenJDK and OracleJDK.
Searching I found the quick way to do it and I want to share it here for you.

1. Go to the system environment variables: Win+X > System > Advanced configuration > Environment variables
2. Do double click on System variables in Path variable
3. Do click on "New" and put this `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
4. Move the new path to the top like in this picture: [image: Environment variable list]
5. Do click in "OK"
6. Create a new .bat file to set the `JAVA_HOME` with the following script:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
echo Display java version
java -version
```

7. Run the .bat as admin, and it's done, we are using the OracleJDK.

**Notes:**

1. The not closed **"** is not an error.
2. To use the OpenJDK create a new .bat and only change path in the setx line:

```
setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.9.101-hotspot
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, it's fine if you want to self-answer questions (in fact, it's very welcome!). but please post the "answer" part as an actual answer and formulate the question as if you wanted someone else to answer it.

Comment: I want to edit this question to put the answered part in his respective place, but the question is closed now and I cant put new answers. But, thank you, I will take it in account in future,

Comment: *"(in fact, it's very welcome)"* ... providing that it isn't repeating an existing Q&A.  (So make sure that you search for existing relevant Q&A's before you spend time on this.)

Comment: Way forward:  1) Check that you are not wasting your time (see above).  2) Edit the question to be a proper question, saving your answer ... somewhere else.  3)  Wait until the question is reopened.  4) Post your  answer.